# Find the missing values

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

As you guess, you need to find the values of question marks in the photo below:

[image]

```
1   2   3   5
2   5   8   3
3   3   6   9
4   4   9   3
5   3   9   2
6   1   7   8
7   4   3   1
8   5   3   2
9   ?   ?   1
```

Comment: Grr. I found a rule that works for rows 1-6 but not 7 or 8 >:-( the rule, slightly modified a tiny bit, works for 7 and 8 );

Comment: @HyperNeutrino  i guess what your rule is, you just need to modify your rule a bit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the pattern is:

> |AB - CD| = BC
>  Where ABCD are the digits (numerals) in the rows,
>  concatenation is simple (decimal) concatenation,
>  and |…| is absolute value.
>  For example, |12−35| = |−23| = 23.

So according to this, we can now try to find the missing numbers:

> 9XY1 = 9X - Y1 = XY
>  so X-1 = Y(unless X=0, but then we get 9091 and 90 - 91 != 9)
>  and now we also know that 9-Y = X

Adding this two together we get:

> X-1=Y
>  9-Y=X
>  Therefore, 9-Y-1=Y ==> 8 = 2Y ==> Y = 4
>  And this only leaves one option for X: 9-4=X ==> X = 5

So the numbers of last row are:

> 9541

Answer (score -2):

5 4 are the answers for the ? that appear in the last row !

The logic obtained for the above answers goes like this: Take the first two digits and the number formed by it and then reverse the digits. With these two operations you get a pair of numbers. If the numbers are different, add twice the difference of those two numbers to the sum of the resulted numbers to get the final answer as the number in the last two columns. That means for example: 2 5  - (number formed by the first two columns) and 5 2 ( by reversing). Now as the numbers are different, add 2 * 3 = 6 to sum of 25 + 52 to get 83 as the answer, which appear as the last two columns .. till certail level such as the central row, after which the trend changes ...

Comment: I assume the downvoters are expecting an explanation for your solution.

Comment: I don't follow your solution.  If the last row is 9554, then 95 + 59 = 154.  5-9=-4 (or 9-5=4, but neither works).  154+(-4)*2=146.

Comment: @LeppyR64, as per my logic, the last row should be 9541 ... but not 9554... please check :-)

Comment: I know your last row should be 9541. I cannot follow your flow of what you do with it.  Your instructions are unclear.